# check for file existence using nmake and delete it

Tags: nmake, makefile

I am using Windows version of NMAKE. I would like to check for file existence in a make file. If it exists I need to delete it. Here is my code:

```
!IF EXIST ("C:\ABC.XML")
    @del ABC.XML
!ELSE
    @echo "FILE DOESN'T EXIST
!ENDIF
```

The above code is not working. I could not figure it out the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `!IF`, `!ELSE` and `!ENDIF` are a preprocessing directives and the result of preprocessing must produce a valid makefile. Commands are only allowed as part of what Microsoft calls a [description block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb7966ta.aspx) which are required to start with a dependency line with one or more targets and zero or more dependents.

You can get around this by executing your commands during the preprocessing stage by including them in a preprocessing directive surrounded by [brackets ([])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkxa7sac.aspx). Something like this:

```
!IF EXIST(C:\ABC.XML)
!  IF [del C:\ABC.XML]
!  ENDIF
!ELSEIF [echo FILE DOESN'T EXIST]
!ENDIF
```

The second `!IF` and the `!ELSEIF` directives are used to provide a context for the commands so they're executed during the preprocessing phase.

However I think you'd probably be better moving the `del` command to a description block where it's actually needed. For example if file `ABC.XML` needs to be deleted before it can be rebuilt, use something like this:

```
ABC.XML: ABC.CSV
    -rem The csv2xml translator requires that the XML file not already exist
    -@del ABC.XML 2> NUL
    csv2xml ABC.CSV ABC.XML
```